# A question about field extensions and form of elements in the extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

We know that the extension $F(A)/F$ where $A$ is finite is the set of all rational functions with $Card(A)$ variables.

What is the form of an element in $F(A)$ if we assume that $A$ is countably infinite?

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us how you define $F(A)$ when $A$ is infinite.

Comment: the same thing with the case in which A is finite

Comment: Well I would define $F(A)$ to be the field of rational functions in arbitrarily many variables. This seems to answer your question then, no?